# adding jsp page dropdownlist value to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, html, jsp

I am creating a website by using html tags in jsp page, I add one dropdownlist box, the user wants to select the input value from the list, the selected value should store in the database table. I dont know how to code this. Could you please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

get selected item value from jsp. and in servlet write this code:

```
<%
String selectedValue=request.getParameter("lang");
out.println("Selected Value is: "+selectedValue);

Connection con = null;
  String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
  String db = "jdbctutorial";
  String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
  try{
  Class.forName(driver);
  con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db,"root","root");
  try{
     Statement st = con.createStatement();
     int val = st.executeUpdate("INSERT employee VALUES("'"+"selectedValue"+"'"s);
     System.out.println("1 row affected");
  }
  catch (SQLException s){
  System.out.println("SQL statement is not executed!");
  }

%>
```